# RRAS (Routing and Remote Access) change process priority to "realtime"?

Tags: networking, performance-tuning, rras, windows-server-2012

I have a windows server 2012 running RRAS and some other services.
Beacause of that I guess I have experience some slowdowns and dropout of package.

My question is how to find, and change the priority of the RRAS process to "realtime".
I cant find the process listed in Task Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the priority of a process in `Task Manager` on the `Processes` tab.  You would right click and choose `Set Priority`.  The RRAS service is likely run through `svchost.exe` but I don't have a machine up and running to check that.  You could go to the service and go to properties to see the path to the executable.

However, you don't really provide enough information to determine if that will actually fix the problem (that you don't describe very well).

What other services are running, and have you used the `Resource Monitor` to see if you have an actual bottleneck somewhere?